# Potential Bug with jQuery data() when dynamically chaning attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, bug-tracking

I have no idea if I just found a potential jQuery bug, but check out the following case.

If I'm dynamically changing a `data-ajax-link` attribute and then try to get it's value with `$('something').data('ajax-link');` the value that's retrieved is still the old one before changing it dynamically.

Here is the example. It's a custom dropDown that sets the clicked option to the first child of the ul. The name of the element as well as the data-ajax-link of the first-child is updated with the values of the clicked option … http://jsfiddle.net/RLF3W/1/

```
$('.select .option').live('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
        $(".select .option:not('.darr')").hide();
        selectedOption = $(this).parents("div.select").find(".option:first");

        $(this).siblings().show();
        selectedOption.text($(this).text()).attr('data-ajax-link', $(this).data('ajax-link'));
});

$('.select .option:not(".darr")').live('click', function () {
    $(this).parents("div.select").find(".option:not('.darr')").hide();
});

$(window).click(function() {
    $(".select .option:not('.darr')").hide();
});


$('a#tester').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //var sort = $('#sortb .darr').attr('data-ajax-link');
    var sort = $('#sort .darr').data('ajax-link');

    $('#output').text(sort)

});
```

In my example you can see that after selecting a different option in the dropdown and then hit the test link the value of the data-ajax-link is still the original value, even though it's actually changed if the element is inspected. If I use `.attr('data-ajax-link')` to get  the updated value it works fine.

Am I wrong here and I'm doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting it using `.attr()`, but getting it using `.data()`.

I'm *pretty* sure that when getting via `.data()`, it first looks at its data in `jQuery.cache` to see if the property exists. *Then* if not, it looks for an attribute.

You should just send it via the `data-` attribute but use `.data()` to get and set.

Change this:

```
selectedOption.text($(this).text()).attr('data-ajax-link', $(this).data('ajax-link'));
```

to this:

```
  // Use .data()----------------------v
selectedOption.text($(this).text()).data('ajax-link', $(this).data('ajax-link'));
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/RLF3W/5/